# JQuery .on method not actually detecting new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-on

```
jQuery( document ).on( "click", "#starSort ", function( ) {

  jQuery( ".qa-voting-bookmark.active" ).closest( ".answer" )
  .prependTo( "#starbox" );

  jQuery("#starbox").append(jQuery(".qa-voting-bookmark.active")
  .closest( ".answer" ).get().reverse());
});
```

The above code is what I have.
it works fine before the new elements are created.
the current .answer elements are recreated by another function that refreshes the data.

i tried just going with.

```
    jQuery( "#starSort" ).on( "click", function( ) {});
```

but it doesn't like it. 
Though the button isn't a concern, it doesn't become dynamic.
Only these .answer elements.

edit**
My event listener targets the whole body. 
But when I read about Event Delegation, all the examples are about the button and the dynamic element being the same object.
I want to click a button that is not inside of the list of dynamic objects, and have it change the dynamic objects.

Comment: You need to read about event delegation - if your  element exists when you bind the event, then it's ok.  If you dynamically add the element after you have bound the event, then you should use event delegation

Comment: isn't that what this .on event is supposed to do?

Comment: My event listener targets the whole body. But when I read about Event Delegation, all the examples are about the button and the dynamic element being the same object. I want to click a button that is not inside of the list of dynamic objects, and have it change the dynamic objects.